# Why does my debian wheezy linux refuse to execute this ELF file?

Tags: linux, debian

I just installed EAGLE on my debian wheezy box, but I cannot start the executable:

```
joe@mybox:/opt/eagle-6.4.0/bin$ ll
total 18264
drwxrwxr-x  2 joe joe     4096 Jan  7 17:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 joe joe     4096 Jan  7 17:02 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     1810 Jan  7 06:04 designlink22.png
-rwxrwxr-x  1 joe joe 15507004 Jan  7 17:02 eagle
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe    43100 Dec 13  2011 eagle.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   827283 Jan  7 17:02 eagle_de.htm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   362467 Jan  7 17:02 eagle_de.qm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   743831 Jan  7 17:02 eagle_en.htm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   336086 Jan 12  2012 eagle_hu.qm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe      718 Dec 13  2010 eagleicon16.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     2924 Dec 13  2010 eagleicon50.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   226206 Jan  7 17:02 eagle_zh.qm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     4029 Dec 13  2011 freeware.key
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe      603 Dec 13  2010 pcb-service.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     1768 Apr 21  2008 platforms-lin.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     1907 Apr 21  2008 platforms-mac.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe     2019 Apr 21  2008 platforms-win.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   324383 Jan 12  2012 qt_de.qm
-rw-rw-r--  1 joe joe   272162 Jan 12  2012 qt_hu.qm
joe@mybox:/opt/eagle-6.4.0/bin$ ./eagle
bash: ./eagle: No such file or directory
joe@mybox:/opt/eagle-6.4.0/bin$ file eagle
eagle: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4,
BuildID[sha1]=0xbc1347e883e2d0da68c6dec32f822d7fac2b52a6, stripped
joe@mybox:/opt/eagle-6.4.0/bin$ uname -anr
Linux mybox 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
joe@mybox:/opt/eagle-6.4.0/bin$
```

I do not have a single clue, why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The executable is 32-bit, and your Debian install is 64-bit. You need to install the appropriate 32-bit libraries. Try installing `ia32-libs` first, I believe that is how you get the 32-bit libraries on Debian.

Comment: But would that give the "file not found" error?

Comment: @terdon: `./eagle: No such file or directory` doesn't mean that *./eagle* couldn't be found. It means that *./eagle* reported that error, i.e., it couldn't find a file (e.g., a library) it needs.

Comment: @Dennis thanks, I am more used to `foo: bar: no such file or directory`.

Comment: Which imho is a quite misleading error message, but of course you were right, though it's not `ia32-libs` I had to install, but `libc6-i386`.

Comment: @Ian, please specify the exact OS version when you ask a question. For instance, Wheezy gained multiarch support which made co-existence of 32-bit and 64-bit applications easier. Also AFAIK the correct way to tell `apt-get` what H/W architecture you want the package to be built for, you should spell the package name by appending the ":arch" suffix to it, like `libc6:i386`.

Comment: @kostix I do have Debian Wheezy.